# Small earthquake happening every night at the exact same time

Tags: seismology

I experience this weird feeling for the last three months. Every night, at exactly 3AM I can feel small earthquake and I could not find anything on the internet related to it. Does anyone have any information about this.

Edit.
I live in Europe, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Mostar.

Comment: Which part of the world do you live & is there a mine near where you live? Mines usually conduct blasts at specific times of the day & night. Such blast can feel like earthquakes. A regular earthquake at 3 am, suggest mine blasting, or underground tunneling may be the cause.

Comment: @Fred I live in Europe, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Mostar and there are no any mine blastings near me nor tunneling so i think it gotta be earthquakes but could not find any information about this

Comment: I don't know your specifics, but would this help? https://www.volcanodiscovery.com/earthquakes/today.html

Comment: Link is helpful, thank you. What is bothering me is that I was watching at the clock and just as it showed 3:00AM it started shaking a bit. Really intriguing

Comment: [My initial search](https://earthquaketrack.com/p/bosnia-and-herzegovina/recent) reveals nothing about small regular earthquakes in your region. There was a magnitude 5.4 quake in Blagaj about 17 hours ago, 26 Nov 2019, 09:19 UTC.

Comment: I started feeling it like three months ago and Im thinking that those are smaller ones, releasing energy periodically. Its just strange that it is the same time always. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: can you give more details in your question,like have other people registered this and have you observed movement of the water in a cup-sink-tub.the source of the shaking might be tens of kilometers away,earthquakes sounds unlikely to me as they are normally random.

Comment: Earthquakes cannot be predicted with precision. The exact predictability of yours suggests some kind of human activity.

Comment: Some heating systems go to a lower temperature overnight and come on in the morning (although not that early). Possibly a scheduled bus/train/truck hitting a bump. Diurnal thermal expansion/contraction of roof?

Comment: this is a good source for earthquake information https://www.emsc-csem.org/#2